# error in touch command

Tags: linux, unix, docker

hi i'm creating docker image, i need to automatically open jenkins page in browser, for that i need to place my host system's(windows) ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. after many website reference i tried this code

```
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir /jenkins/
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion

RUN apt-get install -y sudo \
 adduser admin \
 echo "admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/admin \
 chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/admin \
 su - admin -c "touch me"

CMD ["su", "-", "admin", "-c", "/bin/bash"]

    enter code here

RUN mkdir ~/.ssh \
 chmod 700 ~/.ssh \
 touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys \
 chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys \
 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
RUN ssh -v ********@192.168******* 'DISPLAY=:0 start http://192.168******:8080'
```

When i try to build image i m getting this error

```
Step 19/22 : RUN apt-get install -y sudo  adduser admin  echo "admin ALL=(root)
NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/admin  chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/admin  su - admi
n -c "touch admin"
 ---> Running in bec9f6cc1c7a
E: Opening configuration file touch admin - ifstream::ifstream (2: No such file
or directory)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y sudo  adduser admin  echo "admin ALL=
(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/admin  chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/admin  su
 - admin -c "touch me"' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

1. Can some one help with error correction
2. Next procedures to be done
   3.I want to understand what "su - admin -c "touch me"" line doing?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better *approach* could be:

```
RUN apt-get install -y sudo \
 adduser admin \
 echo "admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/admin \
 chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/admin 

USER admin
RUN touch me
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: can i get answer for my 2nd and 3rd question?? @klashxx